# Azure hosting server - Godaddy DNS - need to create SPF for Azure hosting server

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, spf

Greetings StackOverflow!

I'm unsure how to produce an SPF record from my Azure hosting server to authorize it to send emails on behalf of the GoDaddy DNS. I've searched through Azures support but am only able to find some info on creating an SPF in the Azure DNS(which I didn't really read as it didn't seem to be related).

I do know that I need to add a txt record to the GoDaddy DNS - I just don't know what that record is supposed to look like. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually SPF record for Azure has nothing different from common SPF record in the format.

You can create a TXT record `v=spf1 ip4:<your Azure site ip> -all` to authorize the site to send email. Azure site IP is on Custom Domain Panel in Azure Portal.

Or if you have created a MX record for your Azure hosting server(as a custom mail server), you can use `v=spf1 mx -all` as the TXT record.

Here's my result on [test site](https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester). You can have a try after creating the record.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful and highlights my lack of experience with SPF. I really appreciate your help! If I may, with the MX record, as this may be  what I need to add - I'm unsure - do I just use that line "v=spf1 mx -all" or do I need to include the server ip just like the above for the azure record? Thank you!